# Python Numpy add an array at array index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm struggling with something that may be very simple or not possible.

I want to add an numpy array to another numpy array at a specific index.

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(17, 1, 2))

for i in range(10):
  b = [i]
  c = [1,2,3,4]
  b.append(c)

  # Here I want to add b in a at specific index but it's not working
  # np.append(a[i][0][0], b)
```

At the end I want something like that :

```
a = [[[[0, [1,2,3,4]], ....]]]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not very clear and you do not say what actually is going wrong. You are not doing anything with a in the loop for example. Also you are trying to mix lists and arrays.
Still, I think I know what you mean/need.
You can use insert and append for lists, as illustrated in the example below:

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
  b = [i]
  c = [1,2,3,4]
  b.insert(1,c)
  a.append( b )
print a
```

**Update**

Use [list.insert(index, obj)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm) to insert an object at a specific index.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've commented what I'm doing with a in the loop. You answer don't insert at a specific index unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If the following is not near to what you'd like, you'll really have to be more specific, dear OP.

I acknowledge `numpy` to be a powerful library, but you ask it to initialize zeros, which are `int` then want to add in `list`. You cannot expect the constructor to know at creation time that it needs to allocate space for `object` type data. What you want is to help the numpy ndarray constructor with type inference.

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(17, 1, 2), dtype=object)
for i in range(10):
  b = [i]
  c = [1,2,3,4]
  b.append(c)
  a[i] = b
a
#array([[[0, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],
#
#  [[1, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],
#
#  [[2, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],
#
#  [[3, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],
#
#  [[4, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],

#  [[5, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],

#  [[6, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],

#  [[7, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],

#  [[8, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],

#  [[9, [1, 2, 3, 4]]],

#  [[0, 0]],

#  [[0, 0]],

#  [[0, 0]],

#  [[0, 0]],

#  [[0, 0]],

#  [[0, 0]],

#  [[0, 0]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I needed

Comment: Good to hear. Then I hope to see the green check mark signalling a formal acceptance of the answer, so other people having the same problem/wish can quickly find what they are looking for. ;)

Comment: I dit it but since I have less than 15 reputations the answer doesn't become green